# in chrome devtools, is there any way to detect and break when a javascript variable has been modified?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

in various unix/linux debugging tools it was possible to trap when a particular variable (memory location, internally) is modified in order to identify the offending culprit -- is there any equivalent in chrome devtools?  setting a watch only has effect at someother break.  setting a live-expression is nothing more than pooling. if your suggestion depends polling - this will not trap and identify the offending code.  if your suggestion depends upon setting a breakpoint at a particular line of code - this, too, does not identify the bad actor.

context: trying to detect when an execution stack has been corrupted.  the code manipulating the stack, has, as I said breakpoints set darn near everywhere the stack is being modified, (whereever there is a push/pop) but to no avail, so my delineating the code itself here will be of no use for this question.

Comment: Are you asking about variable assignments or about object (/array) modifications?

Comment: There's no such feature in devtools and no solution for a variable but for object properties or array elements you can emulate it by redefining the property via Object.defineProperty with a getter and a setter.

Comment: thank you for the comments. seems like a decent way to set a trap.  after I get done draining the current swamp, I will try to post a solution template.